# Does escape order of strings matters in some way? (HTML and SQL injection)

Tags: php, html, escaping, sql-injection

We are developing a small website at school, so we were introduced to SQL injection in PHP and how to prevent it.

However I see most online examples and text books doing the following

```
$str = $_POST['user_input'];

$str = $mysqli->real_escape_string($str);
$str = htmlentities($str);
```

However I think the most logical way to validate input from users is:

```
$str = htmlentities($str);
$str = $mysqli->real_escape_string($str);
```

Does that make any difference for

- Site accessibility (characters showed to end user, the string will just be "echoed" once retrieved from Database)
- Preventing HTML and SQL injection (does wrong order allows injection?)
- Performance of the server (for example one function is most expensive while the other increase string lenght, or just because the final string lenght is different and we want to save bytes on our Database)

?

Would be nice to cover also more escaping functions (maybe there is some dangerous combination/order that we should avoid).

I think that the right way is to search for escaping functions that outputs "dangerous characters" (dangerouse as HTML or as SQL, if any exist) and then just provide an input that generate those dangerous characters.

Comment: You don't need `htmlentities()` until you output your content. No need to do it before you save your data in the db.

Comment: If you're using MySQLi, learn to use bind variables

Comment: Jhon Conde, that way everytime I retrieve the data I have to escape it, assume I work with crappy developers that don't do that.

Comment: Mark, I'll try :) seems interesting

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Nobody can make crappy developers secure, they'll always find a way to shoot their own foot. Storing HTML entities in the database where they don't belong is not the answer.

Comment: deceze, nice website! It is also funny to read, I'll propose it to our teacher (wich is always looking for nice websites to link after each lesson). However mysql is deprecated, now we should use mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order will result in different output.

The following code:

```
$string = 'Example " string';
echo htmlentities($mysqli->real_escape_string(($string))
    . "\n"
    . $mysqli->real_escape_string((htmlentities($string));
```

Results in:

```
Example \&quot; string
Example &quot; string
```

The output is different because if you escape the string before converting to HTML entities, it has a quote that needs escaping whereas if you do it in the reverse order the quote is replaced with the HTML entity and is a valid string value for MySQL.

That said, the two functions have entirely different purposes.

`htmlentities` is for converting strings to their HTML entities ready for output to a web browser.

`real_escape_string` is for converting a string for use between quotation marks in a MySQL query.

The two do not go together, you should store the text in the database (which will need escaping before being passed to) and convert to HTML entities when it comes to displaying it.

If you insist on storing the HTML entities version of the string in the database the correct way is to use `htmlentities` first, then escape it. Escaping of a string should be the last operation on it before passing to the database.

Doing it in the wrong way may result in stray backslashes as shown above, although when passed to MySQL these will actually be ignored as `\&` is not a valid escape sequence. You would only notice a difference if outputting the variable that was passed to the database (as opposed to later retrieving it from the database and then outputting it).

You may also want to look into prepared statements in `mysqli`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php